# Why does it give me an error even though I declared rand?

Tags: java, random

```
import java.util.Random;

class perro{
    private Float animo;
    private Float umbral;
    Random rand = new Random();
    
    public perro(){
        animo = rand.nextFloat() * (5+5)-5;
        umbral = rand.nextFloat() * (0-20);
    }
    
    public Float getAnimo(){
        return animo;
    }
    
    public Float getUmbral(){
        return umbral;
    }
    
    private void psican(persona p){
        this.animo = (rand.nextFloat() -0.5) * 10 + this.animo;
        if (p.tieneGalleta()){
            p.darGalleta();
            this.animo += (1.0 / p.getConfiabilidad()) * (rand.nextInt(2));
        }
    
    System.out.println("Mi nuevo animo es: " + this.animo);
    }
```

I received this error:

```
 "error: incompatible types: double cannot be converted to Float
            this.animo = (rand.nextFloat() -0.5) * 10 + this.animo;"
```

I have checked everything however, everything was stated as a float from the beginning.

Comment: In Java, -0.5 will by default be considered a double. You need to explicitly cast to a float (-0.5f).

Answer (score 5):

Because `0.5` is a `double` (not a `float`). Change this

```
this.animo = (rand.nextFloat() -0.5) * 10 + this.animo;
```

to

```
this.animo = (rand.nextFloat() -0.5f) * 10 + this.animo;
```

or

```
this.animo += (rand.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 10;
```